# When I use "WHERE user_id in ( sub query )" generate syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table used below.

Users have referal_code, refered_by columns.Users has following data.

```
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | referal_code | refered_by |
+----+--------------+------------+
|  1 | abc          | null       |
|  2 | xxx          | abc        |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

I have `Reviews` table in which I store users reviewe by other users.
It does have `user_id`, evaluation columns.

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | evaluation |
+----+---------+------------+
| 28 |       2 |          4 |
| 32 |       2 |          6 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to count users referred by each user have an average evaluation of 3 or more.

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(
        SELECT reviews.user_id FROM reviews 
        WHERE reviews.user_id IN( 
           SELECT A2.id FROM users as A2 WHERE A2.refered_by = users.referal_code
        )
        HAVING AVG(evaluation) >= 3) as total_3_estrelas
FROM users
WHERE 1
```

I have a syntax error #1064  on: WHERE `user_id` IN

The result I expect:

```
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
| id | referal_code | refered_by | total_3_estrelas |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
|  1 | abc          | null       |                1 |
|  2 | xxx          | abc        |                0 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I cannot find a reference for this but mysql does not like a select clause in an aggregate function.

Comment: The result is:
**user id 1** have one referral that an average evaluation of 3 or more. **user id 2** have 0 referrals that have an evaluation 3 or more.

Comment: How from this data do you know that 2 was reviewed by 1?

Comment: can be reviewed by anyone. I just want to know: How many of each user referrals have been reviewed with an AVG of 3 or more.  
Anyone @Gufus code works. 
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this if it helps:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.REFERAL_CODE, A.REFERED_BY, COALESCE(TOTAL_3_ESTRELAS,0) AS TOTAL_3_ESTRELAS
FROM USERS A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT REFERED_BY, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_3_ESTRELAS
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN (SELECT USER_ID, AVG(EVALUATION)
FROM REVIEWS 
GROUP BY USER_ID
HAVING AVG(EVALUATION)>=3) R
ON U.ID=R.USER_ID
GROUP BY REFERED_BY) T
ON A.REFERAL_CODE=T.REFERED_BY;
```

From the deeper nested condition, first I calculated the average evaluation for each user_id on REVIEWS throwing away USER_ID with avg below 3, then I made the inner join with USERS and I grouped by REFERED_BY to obtain the count desired. Finally I did a left join to obtain the output in the form you expect.